# How to increase heap space in JCreator

Tags: java, heap-memory

I know this question has been answered before for Eclipse but can someone tell me how to increase heap space of my **JCreator** for a program in a bit more detailed manner (I am a beginner to Java programming).

Note: using `-Xms248m -Xmx3072m` in *cmd.exe* did not work

I had written

```
java -Xms256m -Xmx3072m MyClassName
```

The error occurred when i was making a large array to make a prime number seive up to a billion numbers.

I have 4GB of ram.

```
public class MyClassName {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[] = new int[1000000000];
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a thought: if you plan to collect primes, you only need an array as big as the number of primes you're going for. So unless you want the 1000000000th prime, probably you can decrease the size of that array anyway.

Comment: yes i think @fejese is right